# Shiny App unable to start on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to deploy a `Shiny` app on the `Shiny server` but not able to access the app from the local server URL.

[image]

This is the output of `/var/log/shiny-server.log`:

```
[2016-04-11 21:39:24.302] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
[2016-04-11 21:42:29.564] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:42:29.570] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:43:15.156] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:43:15.163] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:43:28.593] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:43:28.604] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:43:54.549] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:51:52.528] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:52:20.004] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:52:20.020] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:52:26.843] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:56:10.938] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2016-04-11 21:56:10.946] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/r-67anFg6rA) could help.

Comment: This, https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/153, especially the point of having the right permission to access in shiny-server.conf, "run_as", was helpful to me.

Comment: What helped me was adding **sanitize_errors off;** to /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

Comment: This kind of error usually occurs for me when some package is not installed

Comment: Or R is not correctly installed. The error states that the base-package can't be found. What if you reinstall base R?

Comment: Please gothrough the link https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/353

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this situation before when my R code was failing.  Since I write my R code on a windows machine and run my shiny server on ubuntu, some packages work fine in on windows but fail in ubuntu or if I forget to install the package on the ubuntu machine.  To find out when that's happening you have to go to the apps log not the servers log.

There should be a log specific to your app in:

`\var\log\shiny-server\YourAppName-20191112-170851-44977.log`

The numbers after App Name have to do with the timestamp of when the app tried to run.  This log file will contain the R output if there are any errors with specific packages or your R code causing the app to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/153).
I would focus on this error

> [2016-04-11 21:39:24.302] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838

On the provided link you'll find that a couple of user double checked permissions: on port 3838 and on the shiny server.

Furthermore I recommend to have a look at [this guide](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/).
I was able to run my shiny app on an Ubuntu RStudio server by following it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and all of my logs were empty / unopenable.  After much banging my head against the wall I was able to fix this by changing the shiny user in the conf file (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf).

I changed "run_as shiny;" to "run_as :HOME_USER: shiny;".

Also, this:

https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

was more helpful than anything I could find on stackoverflow, github, or google groups.