# Shiny-server serving directory index instead of the application

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am fairly new to using shiny-server which could be why I'm not able to figure this out. Installed shiny-server and all its dependencies on an ubuntu 18.04 lts server for deploying my applications built with R. i copied the folder containing my app along subfolders containing my data files to the /srv/shiny-server under a folder called 'app'. after that headed over to my browser to view the application interface but instead got a list of the directory content as shown below.

[index of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTB7n.png)

I appreciate all the help i can get on this. Thank you

Comment: Your shiny file should be named `app.R`

Comment: Is it a must? if not, is there a way i can configure it to run it as dashboard.R?

Comment: No I don't think any easy way to do this. You can ask this question separately. Shinyserver and shinyapps.io requires file to be named app.R or ui.R/server.R to work.

Comment: May I know why you want to have the file as dashboard.R

Comment: Oh its okay, renaming it to app.R did eliminate the issue but am getting this 'An error has occurred, The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization.' error.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554331/shiny-app-unable-to-start-on-shiny-server). Let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. checked the error logs and found out that Rstudio wasn't running on the server due to this line 'setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))' which i then commented out and the server was able to display the app. thanks again